# C# FolderBrowserDialog RootFolder "Mycomputer" not functioning on Windows 10

Tags: c#

Using Visual Studio 2015, I am writing a Windows Form Application in C#. I use the following code:

```
FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
dialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
```

On my development machine (Windows 8.1) this works as expected, the `FolderBrowserDialog` appears with "This Computer" as the root directory.

However when I transfer the program to a windows 10 machine (I have tried both pro and home versions of Windows 10) the `FolderBrowserDialog` opens with "Desktop" as to root directory.

Is there a different `SpecialFolder` that I should be using specific to Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know MyComputer was renamed to ThisPC in Windows 8 and 10 so interesting that would work in 8 but not 10.  What path do you get if you run this:

`string myComputerPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);`

Does it resolve to  'This PC'.

Also you could try this, which gets the path by the MyComputer Guid:

```
FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
dialog.SelectedPath = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}";
```

Comment: I attempted both suggestions and here are the results:

`string myComputerPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);` resolves to an empty string (Length = 0) in both Windows 8.1 and 10.

`dialog.RootFolder = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}";` won't compile because `RootFolder` is looking for a `System.Environment.SpecialFolder` not a string.

Comment: Hi agthatch i updated my answer you can use the SelectedPath property to set the string path.

Comment: Thanks David, that highlights "This PC" in the list but does not expand it to show the local drives. It also still displays the extra folders such as "One Drive", "Library" and "Control Panel" which are irrelevant for my application and will likely confuse the end user eventually.

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer)` is always going to return an empty string because it's a logical, not physical folder.